# How to make a function write code in its place

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I want it so that whenever I write this code

```
drawCode(var1,var2,var3);
```

the code in the function will be put in its place

```
Function drawCode(var1,var2,var3) {
    posx + var1 * scale, posy + var2 * scale, var3
}
```

### For Example

This code:

```
drawTriangle (drawCode(50,20,180));
```

Will become:

```
drawTriangle (posx + 50 * scale, posy + 20 * scale, 180);
```

### For Context

I'm creating triangles in p5js which need 3 points of x and y. all of which I need to multiply with a set scale and place points relative with each triangles position. I am at an advantage since I am making a square with these triangles, this allows me to put 30 * scale into a variable. This is the best I can do:

```
let triSize = 30 * scale;
triangle(posx - triSize, posy + triSize, posx, posy, posx + triSize, posy + triSize);
triangle(posx + triSize, posy + triSize, posx, posy, posx + triSize, posy - triSize);
triangle(posx - triSize, posy - triSize, posx, posy, posx - triSize, posy + triSize);
triangle(posx - triSize, posy - triSize, posx, posy, posx + triSize, posy - triSize);
```

Ideally I would clean up the code a bit and turn it into:

```
triangle(placePoint(-30,30),placePoint(0,0),placePoint(30,30))
triangle(placePoint(30,30),placePoint(0,0),placePoint(30,-30))
triangle(placePoint(-30,-30),placePoint(0,0),placePoint(-30,30))
triangle(placePoint(-30,-30),placePoint(0,0),placePoint(30,-30))
```

Which would be a more elegant solution especially if I wanted my triangles to have more complex shapes

Comment: You can have code return functions, but really unsure how you would get the results you are after..... Maybe a better explaination on why it needs to do it with some code and we can point you in a better direction.

Comment: Like @epascarello said, it’d be helpful to know why you think you need a solution like this. My gut says, you actually need some generic/abstract code (rather than “code that writes code”, I.e. a macro,) but you don’t have experience writing that kind of code.

Comment: you could have drawCode return an array of your calculated values, and use the spread operator on the returned array,or use rest parameter to get them passed as separate arguments. But that isn't really _"writing code in its place"_ if that is what you are trully going for

Comment: The problem is if it were a simple transformation it would be easy, but having the variables `posx` and `posy` in it that seem like will change is not that easy.... seems like a better solution would be to rewrite a method to handle alter values and than call the original method.

Comment: Now the edit helps. Any way you code it, you are still going to have stuff that repeats. One way to clean it up would be to put `30 * scale` into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way you can do it is to reduce it down to basics and have it call a function that actually calls triangle with the values you pass in.

```js
function triangle() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

var scale = 2

function makeTriangle(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
   var actScale = 30 * scale;
   triangle(x + x1 * actScale, 
            y + y1 * actScale,
            x + x2 * actScale, 
            y + y2 * actScale,
            x + x3 * actScale, 
            y + y3 * actScale);
}

var posx = 1
var posy = 1

makeTriangle(posx, posy, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
makeTriangle(posx, posy, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1)
makeTriangle(posx, posy, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1)
makeTriangle(posx, posy, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1)
```

Now you can clean it up a bit more by returning a function and calling those functions with posx and posy

```js
function triangle() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

function makeTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
  return function (x, y, scale) {
    var actScale = 30 * scale;
    triangle(x + x1 * actScale, 
            y + y1 * actScale,
            x + x2 * actScale, 
            y + y2 * actScale,
            x + x3 * actScale, 
            y + y3 * actScale);
  }
}

var t1 = makeTriangle(-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
var t2 = makeTriangle(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1)
var t3 = makeTriangle(-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1)
var t4 = makeTriangle(1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1)

var posx = 2
var posy = 2
var scale = 4

t1(posx, posy, scale)
t2(posx, posy, scale)
t3(posx, posy, scale)
t4(posx, posy, scale)
```

And you can even go more extreme in combining all those makeTriangle calls into one method. Using an array and looping over it.

```js
function triangle() {
  console.log(arguments);
}


var coords = [
  [-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1],
  [-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1],
  [1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1]
]

function makeTriangle(x, y, scale) {
  coords.forEach( function(a) {
    var actScale = 30 * scale;
    triangle(x + a[0] * actScale, 
            y + a[1] * actScale,
            x + a[2] * actScale, 
            y + a[3] * actScale,
            x + a[4] * actScale, 
            y + a[5] * actScale);
  })
}




var posx = 2
var posy = 2
var scale = 4

makeTriangle(posx, posy, scale)
```

In the end no mater how you do it, you just change the amount of copy and paste code and repetition and add more complexity to the problem. And each solution might end up making it run slower/faster. In the end it really depends on what the goal is and how it is being used.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer, I edited my code using your comment from earlier. To me that's the best way to go about it. This obviously isn't a huge issue for me and just wanted to see if it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you want to do is to return multiple values and use them as arguments in another function. while multiple return is NOT supported in javascript, you can still achieve this using:

1. Return an array in the inner function like `drawCode = (a,b,c) => [d,e,f]` then spread it into arguments like `drawTriangle(...arrayOfdef)`
2. Or you can use some thing like function composition or function currying to compose the two functions together.

Comment: not sure how that will handle the variable situation of `posx` and `posy`. Solution will handle known values.